# How to update a field in MySQL with session_start working and determined by the id

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to create a space for my users where they can change their names of his/her accounts, etc. 
I investigate a lot but I can't find something safely. Now I'm just trying to do work. 
I insert my users with a simple INSERT:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (Name, Email, Password, metodop, social1, social2, aboutt) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$passHash', '$metodop', '$social1', '$social2', '$aboutt')";
```

This is part of the INSERT:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$metodop = $_POST['metodop'];
$social1 = $_POST['social1'];
$social2 = $_POST['social2'];
$aboutt = $_POST['aboutt'];
```

But I want to create now something to Update these fields that the user can use, but I don't know how because I don´t want to leave something that one user can edit the whole database. And here I'm working with session_start. I want to leave that the user that is login can update his data in my data table. 
This is what I figure it out but it doesn't work:

```
$data = [
    'name' => $name,
    'surname' => $surname,
    'social1' => $social1,
    'id' => $id,
];
$sql = "UPDATE users SET name=:name, surname=:surname, social1=:social1 WHERE id=:id";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
?>
```

UPDATE:
Hi, I work hard this days with what I have, and I have this:

PDO for update the data of a user:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
?>
<html>
<?php
 /*Incluyendo la conexion y enviando el Arreglo Files a la funcion*/
 include 'pd.conn.php';
 if(isset($_POST['update']))
 {
        
   
   // data sent from form login.html 
   $email = $_POST['email']; 
   
   
   
            
       
        
  $bemail = $_POST['email']; //by get session value in login form

  $sqlgetid = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE Email = '$email'";
  
        
        $q = $pdo->query($sqlgetid);
        $stmt->bindParam(":Email", $email); //this is the line where i get all this errors//
  $email = $bemail;
    
  $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  while ($row = $q->fetch()){
   $verify_id = $row['id']; //user id value set to verify_id variable
  }
  
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET Name=:Name, social1=:social1, social2=:social2, aboutt=:aboutt WHERE id=:id";
  
   if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(":Name", $param_Name);
    $stmt->bindParam(":social1", $param_social1);
    $stmt->bindParam(":social2", $param_social2);
    $stmt->bindParam(":aboutt", $param_aboutt);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $param_id);
  
    // Set parameters
    $param_Name    = $Name;
    $param_social1 = $social1;
    $param_social2 = $social2;
    $param_aboutt  = $aboutt;
    $param_id      = $verify_id;
  
    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if($stmt->execute()){
     // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
     header("edit-profile.php");
     exit();
    } else{
     echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
            }
             
 }
?>
<div class='alert alert-success mt-4' role='alert'><strong>Welcome!</strong><?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?? ""; ?></div>
<form method="post">                            
        <div class="form-group">         
         <input method="post" class="form-control input-lg" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre" >        
        </div>       
        <div class="form-group">        
         <input method="post" class="form-control input-lg" name="social1" placeholder="social11" >       
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group">        
         <input method="post" class="form-control input-lg" name="social2" placeholder="social22" >       
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group">        
         <input method="post" class="form-control input-lg" name="aboutt" placeholder="about" >       
                                </div>  
                                            
         <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Update</button>
       </form>
```

This is how I insert the new users in my database.

```html
<div class="container">

 <?php

 include 'conn.php';

 $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 
 // Query to check if the email already exist
 $checkEmail = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = '$_POST[email]' ";
 $checkName = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name = '$_POST[name]' ";

 // Variable $result hold the connection data and the query
 $result = $conn-> query($checkEmail);
    $result = $conn-> query($checkName);
 // Variable $count hold the result of the query
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 // If count == 1 that means the email is already on the database
 if ($count == 1) {
 echo "<div class='alert alert-warning mt-4' role='alert'>
     <p>That email or name is already registred, try to change first the name, if it continues getting error, try with another email.</p>
     <p><a href='login.html'>Please login here</a></p>
    </div>";
 } else { 
 
 /*
 If the email don't exist, the data from the form is sended to the
 database and the account is created
 */
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass = $_POST['password'];

 $metodop = $_POST['metodop'];
 $social1 = $_POST['social1'];
 $social2 = $_POST['social2'];
 $aboutt = $_POST['aboutt'];


 // The password_hash() function convert the password in a hash before send it to the database
 $passHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 
 // Query to send Name, Email and Password hash to the database
 $query = "INSERT INTO users (Name, Email, Password, metodop, social1, social2, aboutt) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$passHash', '$metodop', '$social1', '$social2', '$aboutt')";
 
 
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
  echo "<div class='alert alert-success mt-4' role='alert'><h3>Your account has been created.</h3>
  <a class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='login.html' role='button'>Login</a></div>";  
  } else {
   echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  } 
 } 
 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
</div>
```

The conn.php is a simple connection with the database, but diferent that a pdo connection, I recieve this errors, Undefined variable in the $stm, in the upload system, because here the thing that doesn't work is the upload, the insert works good, but is not in pdo. But the upload if I do it in pdo system will be better. And after the thing that I don't really understand is why I get this second error, Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on null. In the same line, where it say. $stmt->bindParam(":Email", $email);
But in upload I use this connection:

```html
 <?php
     define('DB_SERVER', 'xxx.0.0.x');
     define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
     define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
     define('DB_NAME', 'phplogin');

     /* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */

     try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        // Set the PDO error mode to exception
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     }

     catch(PDOException $e) {   
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
     }

?>
```

That is the same.
Thank you so much for the help, you already win my vote, but if we together, solve this problem that would be amazing, what do you thing?

Comment: What is the value you are getting in ID variable?

Comment: You must start the session variable to identifying unique user.

Comment: @sameeralakshitha I made an update about what your answer, ther's a few things that I don't understand, for example, with the session:start I think that makes it unique for the user, about the insert of the data, all goes with a email and I use the email for insert the aditional data. Next to the email is always a number, an id that represents the user, of course a unique number, and I was thinking to use that for make the updates, What to you thing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JackMore I updated my answer. I include PDO database connect code and use the session variable to update function with identifying the unique user.

Comment: @sameeralakshitha can you check the new update that I made, your code looks very good, but I made some changes because my variables are diferent when i insert the new users, and all needs to be connected. I have a problem wth one line, with a $stm bindParam, i don't know how really works but i just learn a lot with all the things that you put. In this update I put all what i have, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I will check your update. I am happy to help you.

Comment: You must start the session in user login time and save the email to a session variable. We can use this save session variable to identify unique users.

Comment: @sameeralakshitha Ok thats a good idea, but for update I think it will be good because I already update my code and now user can use one email, is not going to be two with the same one. But I can't get the update of the data good, there's still the same mistake that some days before. Thank you for your help, happy new year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use secure **PDO** Insert function,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Name, Email, Password, metodop, social1, social2, aboutt) VALUES (:Name, :Email, :Password, :metodop, :social1, :social2, :aboutt)";

if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters

        $stmt->bindParam(":Name", $param_Name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":Email", $param_Email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":Password", $param_Password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":metodop", $param_metodop, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":social1", $param_social1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":social2", $param_social2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":aboutt", $param_aboutt, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        // Set parameters
        $param_Name     = $Name;
        $param_Email    = $Email;
        $param_Password = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
        $param_metodop  = $metodop;
        $param_social1  = $social1;
        $param_social2  = $social2;
        $param_aboutt   = $aboutt;

} else {
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
}
```

Then you need to create a session variable in user login time. So, identify the unique user and give this user permission to change their name.

**Update function**

```
session_start(); //session start
$bemail = $_SESSION['useremail']; //by get session value in login form

$sqlgetid = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE Email=:Email";

$q = $pdo->query($sqlgetid);
$stmt->bindParam(":Email", $param_Email);
$param_Email = $bemail;

$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($row = $q->fetch()){
    $verify_id = $row['id']; //user id value set to verify_id variable
}

$sql = "UPDATE users SET Name=:Name, social1=:social1, social2=:social2, aboutt=:aboutt WHERE id=:id";

    if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bindParam(":Name", $param_Name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":social1", $param_social1);
        $stmt->bindParam(":social2", $param_social2);
        $stmt->bindParam(":aboutt", $param_aboutt);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $param_id);

        // Set parameters
        $param_Name    = $Name;
        $param_social1 = $social1;
        $param_social2 = $social2;
        $param_aboutt  = $aboutt;
        $param_id      = $verify_id;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if($stmt->execute()){
            // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: redirect_page_link_here");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
```

database connect by using **PDO (PHP Data Objects)**

```
<?php
     define('DB_SERVER', 'xxx.x.x.x');
     define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
     define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
     define('DB_NAME', 'phplogin');

     /* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */

     try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        // Set the PDO error mode to exception
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     }

     catch(PDOException $e) {   
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
     }

?>
```